# How can I treat my disk like one big file?

Tags: files, freebsd, devices

I was reading about device files in FreeBSD, but my understanding is not great. To practice, I thought up the following scenario. I suspect that the problem can be solved using device files.

Imagine that I am a part time spy and I need to generate some one-time pad. I could go to my secure FreeBSD box and write some `/dev/urandom` to a pad file, knowing that the randomness coming from this source is Good Enough (tm). My flash drive with pad file will be delivered to my future contact.

However, seeing as this drive will only contain one file full of random bytes, it seems a waste to write a whole filesystem to the disk. Why not fill the USB to the brim with random data?

My question: How can I achieve my aim of reading and writing raw data from and to a disk? Should I point `dd` at the disk's device file?

Comment: Downvote => Bad question. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Because the answer is in your question: dd (or whatever command to the device file).

Comment: Surely there are other ways of interacting with device files? I have read about the _idea_ of a device file, but nowhere can I find an actual protocol for writing to device files.

Comment: If i have understood you question correctly then the below command can be used. `dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=1G count=1` were `1G` can be your whole disk size.

Comment: What happens if you echo some text to the device file? What data does `dd` actually send to the device file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can treat the device file as a raw device file, and read/write data from/to it using the same APIs used to access normal files. In most cases, you can use `dd`, or simply cat data to/from the device file.

Keep in mind that there are several practical differences between raw devices and real files on a filesystem:

- Devices have a fixed size. Writing less data will leave the remaining space intact. You cannot determine how much data you actually wrote unless you have some other way to convey that information.
- Devices have no permissions. *Device files* representing devices have permissions, but those permissions do not travel with the device itself, they are simply assigned by the system to which the device is connected. If you `chmod` a device file representing a USB drive, unplug it, and connect it to another (or the same) system, the permissions changes will not persist.
- Devices have no name, or at least no user-changeable name. Your OS will assign whatever device node name it feels like to your device. Things like volume names are stored in filesystems or partition tables, and there is no such thing when you access the entire device as raw storage.
- Most OSes will not let random non-root users access device files, while some may allow non-root local users to mount things like USB drives.

(Note: I come from a Linux background, but these concepts are pretty much identical on any UNIX-like system)

Comment: I gave `dd` a go but it chokes on the device files. I looked at the manual pages and it seems that I have to wrangle GEOM. Any tips?

Comment: Looks like FreeBSD has protection mechanisms in place to prevent you from writing to devices that are currently in use. Make sure you have unmounted any filesystems on the device. If you have no other option, it looks like setting the `kern.geom.debugflags` sysctl to `0x10` should allow you to bypass the safety.